# To many queries called per request in drupal

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I've built an website using drupal and deployed it. But it very very slow. I installed the  Devel module and see 120 queries per request. And the total execution time is 3000ms. Is this normal?

I just install some module such as: taxonomy menu, simple ads, classified ads, rule, locale. Can anyone suggest how to reduce this?

Comment: uninstall the devel module in production site and then enable all the options in performance settings. At last clear the cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here the link of html output of my [modules](http://tenxanh.vn/admin.html) and my [home page](http://tenxanh.vn/home.html), which include devel information. Can you see some thing make my site slow.Maybe I left some module which need to be uninstalled. I see more than 300 query, and I don't think a website with 300 queries per request is normal. Thanks!

Comment: This is not an answer

Answer (score 3):

First try to debug the website as an anonymous user or any logged in user other than the admin to get more accurate stats.

Then you can consider caching the output to reduce the number of database queries. (faster approaches: cache some blocks in your page using views caching or [block cache module](http://drupal.org/project/blockcache)).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have enabled caching option available in 'admin/config/development/performance' page, aggregating css and javascript could help a lot.

You can also enable views caching in those block in which you think data is not going to change frequently.

For images you can use image cache to reduce size of image from their original size, it could reduce you page size.

For more info you can visit "[Drupal caching, speed and performance](http://drupal.org/node/326504)" page on drupal.org.